# Returning what agent context code is running in?

Tags: netlogo

(Due to Netlogo lacking debugging tools...)

I would like some code to somehow tell what agent context it is in (Observer, turtle id, link, patch etc.). Something like:

```
carefully [set id self] [set id "Observer]
```

But Netlogo does not allow this as the syntax checker dissallows self here.

Any ideas?  An extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `show` to print the context, of course. To actually get the value, you can cheat the syntax checker using `runresult`

```
carefully [ set id runresult "self" ] [ set id "observer" ]
```

Update:

[This comment on github](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/882#issuecomment-158405021) reminded me that tasks can also be used and would be somewhat preferable:

```
carefully [ set id runresult task [ self ] ] [ set id "observer" ]
```